# Using mod_rewrite to make a url prettier

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to use mod_rewrite to change the appearance of my URL's. I am really lost in this and could use some help. First of all, is it possible to use mod_rewrite to alter the "front-end" of a URL and keep it the same internally? If so, how would I do the following:

I have 
`https://domain.com/live/page.php?id=x`
with both "page" and "x" being variable, and would like the URL's to be shown as 
`https://domain.com/page` 
if possible, or if I need the id=x in there then it could be 
`https://domain.com/page/x/`
but I don't know if I need to have that id somewhere in the URL.

Please help me as I know this is a common thing but I just can't figure it out!

Thanks!

EDIT: With the help of anubhava I got this working halfway. This time I put the code into my .htaccess for the /live/ directory not the root one. Now the pages change URL correctly, but I still need the server to load from the original so the new URL's are giving me a 404. Here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+live/([^.]+)\.php\?([^=]+)=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /live/$1.php?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

EDIT:
Here are my current .htaccess files

root:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bidwaffle\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.bidwaffle\.com$

RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/bidwaffle\.com\/live" [R=301,L]
```

and in root\live\:

```
# secure htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>

# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# disable access to logs/template files
<Files ~ "\.(log|tpl)$">
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</files>

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+live/([^.]+)\.php\?([^=]+)=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /live/$1.php?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

The URL changes properly but doesn't load properly (silent loading of the real URL). Right now I see the issue of the second part where it may not even see this request because the /live/ is no longer in the "pretty URL" so the /live/.htaccess might not be called. I tried putting that part into the root/.htaccess and it did the same weird thing with appending the referring page instead of %3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes sure you can have rules like this in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/live/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /live/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php\?([^=]+)=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [R=302,L]
```

root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?bidwaffle\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://bidwaffle.com/live/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /live/$1.php?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I don't see any reason for a downvote here anub's answer seems pretty right to me hence I'm upvoting him.

Comment: Thanks anub, at least I am on the right track now. I edited my question since toying with this answer, if you wouldn't mind taking a look. Thanks!

Comment: But what would be pretty URL for `/live/page.php?id=x&a=y` ?

Comment: I would like it to be /page if possible, and hide as much as I can from the user (they don't need to know all that info). If I need it somewhere in the URL, I am fine with /page/id/x/a/y or something

Comment: check update now. It will convert `/live/page.php?foo=bar` to `/page/foo/bar`

Comment: You can further enhance this rule for multiple query parameters (let me know if you run into any problems).

Comment: anubhava, Thank you for your help so far, I am almost there! It is converting the page URL correctly and I think I can handle increasing the number of parameters but unfortunately the pages aren't loading. In other words, even though the URL shown to the end-user is `/page/foo/bar` the page should still be loaded from/as `/live/page.php?foo=bar` How can I do this?

Comment: That's what rule is already doing i.e. `/page/foo/bar` silently loads `/live/page.php?foo=bar`

Comment: That is what I thought but it is not. Should this be in the root .htaccess or in /live/ ? I have a .htaccess in root that redirects all requests to my domain to /live/ already. When I put these rules in there it was completely messed up, and when I put it in /live/ it works but, like I said, it is not loading the right page.

Comment: see update and make sure these 2 rules are top 2 rules in `/live/.htaccess`

Comment: That doesn't work either. With the previous solution you gave, without those two lines, it changes the visible URL correctly but doesn't redirect to the correct page. With those lines it does something weird. If I go to page2 from page1 and my URL should be `/page2/foo/bar`, it turns into `/page2/foo/page1.php` like it appends the referring page, WITH the .php, to the end of the URL...so far without the two lines it works best, but just seems like the part of the code silently loading the proper page is not working.

Comment: Most likely you have some conflicting rules in this .htaccess. Can you place your `/live/.htaccess` in your question?

Comment: Ok edited and included some more info as well. Thanks for spending so much time on this, I'm sure you have better things to do hahaha

Comment: But I don't see `RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /live/` lines in live/.htaccess also my updated rules look different than your current code

Answer (score -1):

I think you've got it backwards. The *incoming* URI from visitors (and links on your pages) is the SEO (pretty) form: `/page/x`. It is the job of .htaccess to convert the pretty form into the real "dynamic" form: `/live/page.php?id=x` (where both page and x could be extracted from the SEO URI). .htaccess does not modify *outgoing* URIs.

Comment: You can easily redirect `/live/page.php?id=x` to the pretty URL format as seen on anub's answer.

Comment: Don't downvote my answer. It's correct. What is the point of redirecting the dynamic form to the SEO form? It will just have to be redirected back into the dynamic form, which results in a loop.

Comment: That is not correct you can redirect the dynamic externally and the static internally hence it will not be a loop you should try anub's answer before jumping the gun.